# problem using regular expressions with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following script but it's giving syntax errors which I am unable to figure out. Please help.

```
var str = "http://gaurav.com";

var patt1 = /^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$/;
console.log(str.match(patt1));
```

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape all `/` as well:

```
var str = "http://gaurav.com";
var patt1 = /^http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?$/;
//------------------^-^---------------------------------^
console.log(str.match(patt1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs to be in `/`'s

```
var patt1 = /^http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?$/;
```

Edit: also escape `/`s in the pattern.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out... but it's yet not working.

Comment: I tried it in Firebug, there's some kind of syntax error still, maybe unescaped regex meta character?

Answer (score 1):

You pattern gives a "," in the string, could that be the problem???

Try this:

```
var str = "http://gaurav.com";
var patt1 = 'http:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\.-]{3,}\.[A-Za-z]{3}';
console.log(str.match(patt1));
```

See the [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/VD4YG/)

Answer (score 0):

Quote the regexp string, that should fix the error. Haven't checked the expression, but that wasn't the question, right?

```
var patt1 = '^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$';
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine - looks like you're just missing your quotes

```
var str = "http://gaurav.com";

var patt1 = "^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$";
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

Here's a jsfiddle link to the code you can play with http://jsfiddle.net/chuckplayer/fLrx8/